# Is there a way to get syntax highlighting that highlights global and local variables differently in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

Common workflows for me involve taking functions and breaking them apart into multiple functions, taking code that was not in a function and putting it in a function, and/or switching local variables to global variables for access by other functions or other code. This would be faster for me if I had a syntax highlighter that can highlight global variables and local variables differently. Does anyone know an easy way to do this, or can anyone recommend a syntax highlighter for which the code might be easy to modify for this purpose?

I am happy using any editor for this purpose.

Comment: If someone could explain why I'm getting down-voted that would be great.

Comment: can you describe the editor you're using? I know you made a tag, but it looks like you need to make that clearer.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'm actually happy to use pretty much any editor for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your tag it looks like you're using `vim`, in which case you can try the [TagHighlight](http://www.cgtk.co.uk/vim-scripts/taghighlight) plugin, which supports Javascript. It adds a bunch of keywords types like `GlobalVariable`.